# Choosing words from file using bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

How to choose words from file that consist of particular characters?

Suppose I have a file with words, I need words that consists of chars `a,b,c`

/upd I've tried this command: `grep -E "[a,b,c]*.[b]" /usr/share/dict/words`

/upd Example:
file.txt contain:

```
qwerty
asdf
abb
bbb
zxc
abc
```

result must be as:

```
abb
bbb
abc
```

Comment: Is it that it should contain all the three or any of the three, `a, b, c`?

Comment: all combinations with this chars, abc, cba, ccba etc

Comment: Should it also allow characters to not appear, as in e.g. "baa"?

Comment: edit// yes, words as "baa" "a" "aaa" too

Answer (score 2):

May be this is what you are looking for

```
grep -wo "[abc]*"
```

From `man grep`

> -w, --word-regexp
>       Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
>       words.
>
> -o, --only-matching
>                Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching ? line,
>                 with each such part on a separate output line.

**Test**

```
$ cat input
qwerty
asdf
abb
bbb
zxc
abc
qweabcqwe

$ grep -wo "[abc]*"  input
abb
bbb
abc
```

Comment: @Set-xx On `gnu grep` it doesnt. Which version are you using?. Tested in `grep (GNU grep) 2.20`

Comment: no, this command just delete other chars: Example: we have string "qweabcqwe" u just del "qwe"

Comment: @Set-xx Delete characters? I sorry but i didnt get you clearly. I have edited my test case in the answer with the file content as yours

Comment: @Set-xx I am unable to replicate that case. See the updated example where i added `qweabcqwe` to my file. Still it prints ony 3 lines as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you define a word based on whitespace, you could simply do:

```
tr ' ' \\n < input-file | grep -iv [d-z]
```

(The initial tr just puts each word on a separate line)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is wrong.

`[a,b,c]` matches one character which is `a` or `,` or `b` or `,` (well, the duplicate can be ignored, of course) or `c`; and `*` specifies zero or more of them.  So your expression takes none or some of these, followed by a literal `b` (the brackets around it are really superfluous, although you sometimes see `[.]` as a shorthand for a literal `.`, which could equivalently be written `\.` -- a dot by itself is a metacharacter which matches any character, but inside a character class, it loses this metacharacter nature).

Out of the box, `grep` will print any line where a match happens anywhere on the line.

So `grab` will match because it contains `a` followed by `b` as specified by your pattern, and `boor` will match because it contains zero or more of `[a,b,c]` followed by `b`.

You can fix your regular expression to only match entire lines by adding an `-x` option, or by anchoring your regular expression with `^` (beginning of line) and `$` (end of line).

```
grep '^[abc]*$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

or

```
grep -x '[abc]*' /usr/share/dict/words
```

(Your regular expression didn't contain any [extended regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) constructs, so the `-E` option isn't useful or necessary.)

Because `/usr/share/dict/words` contains one word per line, you can use "line" where you mean "word".  In the general case, you might want to try the `-w` option for matching words, as suggested by @nu11p01n73R